# How to resolve missing module Tweepy on Heroku?

Tags: flask, heroku, tweepy

I'm running at python script to automatically tweet updates from my website running on Heroku. The tweepy script is executed every hour. The script works in the local environment but won't execute on Heroku.

The error log is below:

```
    2020-05-02T12:32:41.805232+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/app/main/twitter.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805363+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: import tweepy
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805363+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805500+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from tweepy.api import API
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805503+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 10, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805645+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from tweepy.binder import bind_api
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805647+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 10, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805772+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: import requests
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805832+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805968+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: import urllib3
2020-05-02T12:32:41.805971+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806110+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806114+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806230+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from .exceptions import (
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806266+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806407+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806411+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 199, in load_module
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806614+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: mod = mod._resolve()
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806618+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 113, in _resolve
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806805+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: return _import_module(self.mod)
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806809+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806954+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: __import__(name)
2020-05-02T12:32:41.806957+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807124+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: import email.parser
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807128+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/app/main/email.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807244+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from flask import current_app
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807245+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807371+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from . import json
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807375+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807504+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from werkzeug.http import http_date
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807508+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 218, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807677+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: from .serving import run_simple
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807681+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 59, in <module>
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807876+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: import SocketServer as socketserver
2020-05-02T12:32:41.807879+00:00 app[scheduler.6938]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Import Error is with SocketServer not tweepy.
Import it like this

```
import socketserver
```

Yes, it's socketserver only by default not SocketServer.
[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html)